# Automatically Add Caption in image

Tags: images, uploads

I want to automatically add caption for each picture appears in the name of the image or the alternative text

example Caption add automatic

[image: example]

Comment: http://webtide.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/automatically-add-links-to-wordpress-image-captions/ but for alternate text repeat in caption

Comment: Daniela, please explain and show the code you tried to adapt. You can do that updating the Question: [edit]. How this "automatic" works? Where does the caption text coming from? The screenshot you're showing indicates WordPress pre-3.5. After 3.5 everything changed and became more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can add programmatically caption, alt, description every time you upload image at backend.

https://brutalbusiness.com/automatically-set-the-wordpress-image-title-alt-text-other-meta/

I tried myself this and worked nice as your expectation. This is for all your future upload images.

Try this and let me know.

```
/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

    // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {

        $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;

        // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
        $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

        // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
        $my_image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );

        // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
        // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
            'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
            'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
            'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
        );

        // Set the image Alt-Text
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

        // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To put in a plugin, these solutions came from eskimo and sam..
we simply select all the attachment where the post_excpert is empty and udpate it , put the title of it in description and caption when they are empty

```
    $s_query = "SELECT ID, post_title FROM `wp_posts` WHERE NOT post_content <=> post_title AND post_type='attachment'";
        $r_result = mysql_query($s_query);

        if($r_result)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($r_result)){
                $s_update_query = 'UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content="'.$row[1].'", post_excerpt="'.$row[1].'" WHERE ID="'.$row[0].'"';
                mysql_query($s_update_query);
            }
        }
```

Here another similar query for the same result:

```
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type= 'attachment' AND post_excerpt= ''";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt=post_title WHERE post_type='attachment' AND post_excerpt=''";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
```

So with these solution we can import(SELECT) many image in wp gallery.Firstly the caption doesn't appear, we need to update (UPDATE)the post to see it in front end.

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it works. "these solution came from eskimo and sam.." doesn't count as an explanation. Just a point of note, if you add code to the editor, highlight it, and click on the `{}` symbol above the code to add it in a code block like in the edit I've done

Comment: If you're manipulating the WordPress database, you should probably be using the [`wpdb` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: yes thank you for your reply i tryied using wpdb class but couldn't figure it out...not an expert, unfortunetly!!if someone can improve these queries, it could be great...